# How to forward incoming request to 80 port on host to x port where x is the incoming request parameter

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

My host has 5 services running on say 5 different ports(5000-5004). My host does not accept remote connections on any port except 80. So I need to run some service on port 80 which can accept by incoming request (eg http://1.1.1.1:80?5000) and forward it to the port mentioned in the request (5000 here). Is it possible through Nginx or do I need any other load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com #or your ip, or your host if you prefer

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://your_service_ip.com:$args;

    }

}
```

$args contains anythong after "?".

Of course, this is a basic example, you should add all parameters you need to proxy pass correctly to your services. Another way is mapping the args on a variable called port and proxy to that port.